# Login to website using cURL and PHP

Tags: php, html, json, curl, web

Hey I am trying to login to the NJIT site to check if username and password are correct. For some reason I keep getting rejected even if I use correct credentials. Also how do I strip the $result to check if it contains "Fail" which would mean the credentials were wrong. Here is my code.

Main:

```
<?PHP
session_start();
require_once('functions.php');

//$UCID=$_POST['UCID'];
//$Pass=$_POST['Pass'];

$UCID="jko328";
$Pass="password";
$credentialsNJIT="user=".$UCID."&pass=".$Pass;

$njit_url="https://cp4.njit.edu/cp/home/login";

$njit_result=goCurlNJIT($credentialsNJIT, $njit_url);
echo $result;

?>
```

Here is the cURL function:

```
function goCurlNJIT($postdata, $url){

session_start();

  $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_HTTPS);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    if(strpos($result, "Failed") === false){
       $response = "NJIT did not like credentials";
    }
    else{
       $response = "NJIT liked your credentials";
       }

echo $response;
```

}

Comment: What exactly is outputted to you?

Comment: Are you receiving 403?

Comment: output is the standard "failed username/password not in database" error that njit responds with if you put in wrong credentials. The problem is even when I put in the correct credentials I still get the "username/password" not found error.

Comment: you're doing it completely WRONG.

Answer (score 0):

Actually when we load a page it saves the cookie and send it . So to sign in you first need to acess the page without credential and save the cookies . In next request you need to send the cookies . To avoid bot script login usually websites have dynamic  hidden fields and other securities .. in this case you cant log on .

Comment: I hope this will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142964/curl-cookie-value

Answer (score 0):

I'm updating the function too much and making it way more flexible. --You can update it further more if you want.

**First and most importantly**, you need to create a **`text file`** named `cookie.txt` in the directory where your scrapping file is.

```
function goCurlNJIT($header = array(), $url, $post = false)
    {       
        $cookie = "cookie.txt";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate,sdch');
        if (isset($header) && !empty($header))
        {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);

        }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 200);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, realpath($cookie));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, realpath($cookie));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);

        //if it's a POST request instead of GET

        if (isset($post) && !empty($post) && $post)
        {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
        } //endif
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        if($info['http_code'] == 200){
            return ($data);     //this will return page on successful, false otherwise
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

if you'd paid a close look to `Requested Headers`, you can notice that there is one **unusual header** there, that is **`Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1`**(I personally haven't seen this before, so it's wise to send this along with request).

**Next** the request that you're posting is not like as it should be, you're missing stuff.

```
$UCID="jko328";
$Pass="password";
$credentialsNJIT="user=".$UCID."&pass=".$Pass;    // where is uuid?
```

it should be something like this. You're skipping `uuid` from `post string`.

```
pass=password&user=jko328&uuid=0xACA021
```

so putting altogether,

```
$post['user'] = "jko328";
$post['pass'] = "password";
$post['uuid'] = '0xACA021';
$urlToPost = "https://cp4.njit.edu/cp/home/login";
$header['Upgrade-Insecure-Requests'] = 1;
//Now make call to function, and it'll work fine.
echo goCurlNJIT($header, $urlToPost, http_build_query($post));
```

and this will work fine. Make sure you've created **`cookie.txt`** file in the directory where your this scripts is.